# How to remember toggle button selection according to adapter position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

Iam using sharedprefrence to remember toggle  button selection whenever i reopen application, but problem iam facing that iam using recycler view with cardlayout that when i select toggle button(tg1) and exit application and reenter it select all button in layout instead i want particular button would be remember according to adapter position..below is the code.

```
 public MyViewHolder (View view){
        super (view);
        context= itemView.getContext();
        inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



        im = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1a);
        tg1 = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button1b);
        tg2 = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button1c);
        t1= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1a);
        t2= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1b);
        t3= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1c);

        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences= context.getSharedPreferences("pre",context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean check = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("status", true);
        tg1.setChecked(check);






        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                intent =new Intent(context, Overlay.class);
                click=true;


                int pos= getAdapterPosition();
                switch (pos){
                    case 0:
                        context.startService(intent);
                        container = inflator.inflate(R.layout.preview_layout, null);
                        b11= (Button) container.findViewById(R.id.p1);
                        b11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                               context.stopService(intent);
                                container=null;

                            }
                        });


                        break;
                    case 1:
                        context.startService(intent);


                        break;
                }


            }
        });
        tg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                intent = new Intent(context, Overlay.class);
                click=false;
                int pos= getAdapterPosition();

                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                    if (b) {

                        img = new ImageView(context);
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                        context.startService(intent);
                        SharedPreferences sharedpreferences= context.getSharedPreferences("pre",context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("status",tg1.isChecked());
                        editor.apply();
                    } else {
                        context.stopService(intent);
                        img=null;
                    }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        if (b) {
                            img = new ImageView(context);
                            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                            context.startService(intent);




                        } else {
                            context.stopService(intent);
                            img=null;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Below is image explanation i want..
[image]

Comment: you have to use four different keys to store four toggle button value instead one status key.

Comment: `recyclerview` reuses views, so you should keep information about toggled switches in models you are displaying in `recyclerview` and on bind - restore them.